# Email Regex for Javascript Which not start with Number

Tags: javascript, regex, email

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

i had tried this regex for email but it allow following cases

1. 123@mail.com
2. example.mail@mail.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: That regular expression is terrible. Why would you exclude so many types of valid email addresses (e.g. subdomains, second level domains, many non-country domains, names with a period, hyphen or many other valid characters, ...)? And why would you make it even worse by not allowing leading numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which searches for the number at the start.
If number is matched it prints message in console.

```js
let regex = /^[0-9]/;



let object = [{email:'123@mail.com'},{email:'example.mail@mail.com'}];

for(let i =0;i<object.length;i++){
  if(object[i].email.match(regex)){
    console.log('E-mail  ',object[i].email,' is not valid.')
  }
}
```

This is the used regex: `^[0-9]`